# Telerik MVC Grid in Form tag

Tags: model-view-controller, grid, telerik

I have placed Telerik MVC grid in form.but it it giving me followin problem.
if i edit any row and then click update,then control goes to select method instead of update method of the controller.
can you please suggest me any solution?

Thanks,
Makarand Salvi

Answer (score 0):

The grid is internally generating a  tag because it is needed for editing. However nested forms are not supported by any browser. The only solution is to put the grid out of the  tag.